# How do I know url of a file uploaded to Google Drive from Android?

Tags: android, file-upload, google-drive-api

I have uploaded a file to `Google Drive` by launching Google Drive activity. How can I register a `callback/listener` to know when file upload got completed. Also how can I know the url of uploaded file. (to `share` the url in an Email)